# Keep getting "incorrect password error" upon login

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a login form which accesses details from a MySQL database and then redirects the user to another page. However Whenever I try to login using the correct credentials, I keep getting an incorrect password error. Can anyone see anything wrong with the following code?

```
<?php
// Initialize the session

session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
include "connection.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    //find first name of logged in user


    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";

    } else{
        $email = trim($_POST["username"]);

    // Check if the password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";

    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT Email, Password FROM users WHERE Email = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_email);

            // Set parameters
            $param_email = $email;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $email, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // if the password is correct, begin a new session
                            session_start();

                            // allocate values to session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $email;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page



                            header("location: index.php");



                        } else{
                            // Display error message for incorrect password
                            $message = "Incorrect password, please try again";
                            echo "<script>
                            alert('$message');
                            window.location.href='login.php';
                            </script>";
                            exit;
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $message = "Incorrect username, please try again";
                            echo "<script>
                            alert('$message');
                            window.location.href='login.php';
                            </script>";
                            exit;
                }
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        } else {
            //prevent SQL Injection
            die("Error : " . mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but you have two session_start(). Not sure what that might cause

Comment: `session_start` only starts a new session if you didn't already have one. You probably meant to use e.g. session_regenerate_id to change the session id on login.

Comment: What is the DB  definition of your `Password` column?

Comment: I would debug this by first seeing what the `password_verify()` arguments are, and then check these in isolation. Sidenote: It is a bad idea to give different feedback depending on the correctness of the email or password. That way you leak information to a possible hacker. Also, something is either an email address or a user name, you seem to mix these two up.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware when I debug it it's showing the correct hashed password and correct password entered by the user

Comment: OK, and the result of `password_verify()` is `true`? If that is so then the message "Incorrect password, please try again" should not be shown. However, if it is `false` then you know that the hash that is stored in the database is not the from the same password.

Comment: No password_verify() comes out as false, but the password matches the hashed password so I'm not sure why its coming out false

Comment: Well, that's your problem then. Try to hash the password again with [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and check that the hash is exactly the same. These PHP functions _do work_, so it is just a question of finding out why it returns `false`.

Comment: Are you also trimming the password before you hash it when you set it?

Comment: @jeroen yeah the password is trimmed before it is hashed

Comment: @GeorgeSmith Please add for debugging purposes the call `var_dump($password, $hashed_password);` before your `password_verify()` call. Also, add the `CREATE TABLE` definition of your "users" table. Also, add the source code which adds/sets the password for the user.

Answer (score 0):

This might be me being blind (or that this is just a snippet), but you're not actually opening your connection to MySQL so $link will be null at the point you try to prepare your statement. (Sorry I didn't post this as a comment, I'm too new to this)

Comment: This is most likely happening in `include "connection.php";`.

Comment: I did wonder this, but it seems pointless trying to open a connection if you're not guaranteed to actually use it, so decided connection.php might just contain a connection string or similar.